# C++ Optimized access of unsigned char in class

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a class in C++

```
class clsByteContainer 
{
private:

protected:

public:
    vector<unsigned char>Content;
};
```

I am fill Content with unsigned chars.

```
m_ByteContainer.Content.resize(iByteCount);
memcpy(&m_ByteContainer.Content[0], &((unsigned char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iStartPos],iByteCount);
```

And I access it like this:

```
double dblRes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    unsigned char val1=m_ByteContainer.Content[iStartPos+i];
    unsigned char val2=uTargetFeatureVector_Bytes.Values[i];
    if (val1 != val2)
    {
        dblRes +=1;
    }
}
```

My question is:

Could I speed up / optimize the way I stored the unsigned chars in the the class?

I am not sure if this declaration

```
public:
    vector<unsigned char>Content;
};
```

is really nice or if it could be optimized.

It would be very nice to get help or an opinion on this.

Speed matters most to me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you profiled this and verified that it's a performance problem?

Comment: I did not profile this, and I don't know if there is a performance problem. I only wanted to know if anybody see any way to optimize my code. I am not sure if I did it nicely or not.

Comment: Then don't bother. Optimizing for the sake of optimizing is the worst thing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you should not be trying to hand-optimize this unless you have already isolated it as a speed problem. From the code you have submitted it looks like you have larger outlying problems.

When you populate the array, it appears you are doing so from an array or vector of unsigned characters in the first place.

```
m_ByteContainer.Content.resize(iByteCount);
memcpy(&m_ByteContainer.Content[0], &((unsigned char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iStartPos],iByteCount);
```

It would be generally better to write

```
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;


const uchar_t* voiceData = (uchar_t*)m_pVoiceData + iStartPos;
m_ByteContainer.assign(voiceData, voiceData + iByteCount);
```

And let the container worry about optimization.

In the next piece of code, you have a worrying constant in the for loop:

```
double dblRes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
```

From the code we've seen, there is no reason to think there are 50 bytes in either of the containers. You should either make this an enum or a const variable with a descriptive name, or you should use an accessor of m_ByteContainer or uTargetFeatureVector or something.

```
// in the class:
const size_t MaxTargetFeatures = 50;


// in the code:
if (m_ByteContainer.empty() || m_byteContainer.size() < iStartPos)
    return ...;
const size_t containerBytes = std::min(m_byteContainer.size() - MaxTargetFeatures, iStartPos);
const size_t vectorBytes = std::min(uTargetFeatureVector_Bytes.size(), MaxTargetFeatures);
const size_t maxCompare = std::min(containerEnd, vectorEnd);

const uchar_t* const begin = &m_ByteContainer[iStartPos];
const uchar_t* const end = &m_ByteContainer[iStartPos + maxCompare];
const uchar_t* feat = &uTargetFeatureVector_Bytes.Values[i];
for (const uchar_t* p = begin; p != end; ++p, ++feat)
{
    if (*p != *feat)
        dblRes += 1;
}
```

Also, if this is not a project you are working on for someone else, stop mixing apps and systems notation like that. Apps notation prefixes variables with information describing the role/purpose/kind-of-thing-the-variable-describes, such as putting "m_" infront of members or "countInput" for a variable that increments, while systems prefixes the type of the variable, e.g. "lpszPtr". Modern IDEs have more or less made systems notation redundant and arguably, in a language with templates and overloading, potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I believe memcpy is the fastest way to copy blocks of memory from one location to another. And this should be optimized by the compiler and operating system.

As for te way you declare the destination alocated memory, it shouldn't matter to the memcpy function, since it always assumes its just a chunk of bytes. it only afects the way you will read the data after it's been copyed.

Comment: And what about my accessing of the data?